# VSCode making a keybinding for assigning a value to a setting configuration

Tags: vscode-keybinding

I am trying to write a json keybinding in VSCode for changing a value that is assigned to a specific setting. The setting I have in mind is latex-workshop.view.pdf.invert from Latex Workshop. I want my shortcut to change the value assigned to this setting to 0.85. I tried editing keybindings.json in several different ways but none of them seem to work. Could anyone take a look at the sample (nonworking) keybinding below and tell me how I should fix it?

The keybindings I tried but failed are variations of below

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+v",
    "command": "latex-workshop.view.pdf.invert",
    "args": {"text": 0.85}
},

{
    "key": "ctrl+v",
    "command": "latex-workshop.view.pdf.invert": 0.85
}
```

With this, I would expect the Latex-workshop > View > Pdf: Invert to be assigned the value 0.85.